# spring state machine - manage long running processes

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I need some advice for using spring state machine for long running processes. I want to design some flow. Let's say I have next states: Start->step1->step2->step3->finish. I have a controller that can send events to the state machine for managing transitions between states. I have a StateMachinePersister. I have a converter from StateMachineContext to byte[] and back. Sounds good for my business goal. So everything should work fine.

But I have a problem? I can't understand how to manage cases when  I will decide to change the flow. I mean that if I have a Production environment where some processes persisted in "step2" state. But I am forced to change the flow. let say that I want to add a step or remove a step in the flow. I think I will have problems during state machine deserialization.

So the question is: may be spring state machine is not suitable for me, or there are some recipes how I can manage such cases?

---

I have an entity which I want to manage states, transitions etc.

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Table(name = "processes", indexes = @Index(columnList = "currentState"))
public class Process extends AbstractPersistable<Long> implements ContextEntity<ProcessState, ProcessEvent, Long> { // NOSONAR

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8848887579564649636L;

    @JsonIgnore
    StateMachineContext<ProcessState, ProcessEvent> stateMachineContext; // NOSONAR

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    ProcessState currentState;


    @Override
    public void setStateMachineContext(StateMachineContext<ProcessState, ProcessEvent> stateMachineContext) {
        if (stateMachineContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("stateMachineContext can't be null");
        }
        this.currentState = stateMachineContext.getState();
        this.stateMachineContext = stateMachineContext;
    }


    @Override
    public StateMachineContext<ProcessState, ProcessEvent> getStateMachineContext() {
        return stateMachineContext;
    }

...
}
```

I have StateMachinePersist bean which is responsible for initializing stateMachineContext for particular process.

@Bean
public StateMachinePersist> persist() {
    return new StateMachinePersist>() {

```
    @Override
    public StateMachineContext<ProcessState, ProcessEvent> read(
            ContextEntity<ProcessState, ProcessEvent, Serializable> process) throws Exception {
        return process.getStateMachineContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(StateMachineContext<ProcessState, ProcessEvent> context,
            ContextEntity<ProcessState, ProcessEvent, Serializable> process) throws Exception {
        process.setStateMachineContext(context);
    }
};
```

}

I have StateMachineAdapter which is responsible for persisting and restoring state machine

```
public class DefaultStateMachineAdapter<S, E, T> {

    final StateMachineFactory<S, E> stateMachineFactory;

    final StateMachinePersister<S, E, T> persister;

    public DefaultStateMachineAdapter(StateMachineFactory<S, E> stateMachineFactory, StateMachinePersister<S, E, T> persister) {
        this.stateMachineFactory = stateMachineFactory;
        this.persister = persister;
    }

    public StateMachine<S, E> restore(T contextObject) throws Exception {
        StateMachine<S, E> stateMachine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine();
        return persister.restore(stateMachine, contextObject);
    }

    public void persist(StateMachine<S, E> stateMachine, T order) throws Exception {
        persister.persist(stateMachine, order);
    }

    public StateMachine<S, E> create() {
        StateMachine<S, E> stateMachine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine();
        stateMachine.start();
        return stateMachine;
    }

}
```

I have StateMachineContextConverter which is responsible for serialization/deserialization of StateMachineContext. I have used Kryo for this operations.

```
public class StateMachineContextConverter implements AttributeConverter<StateMachineContext, byte[]> {

    @Override
    public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(StateMachineContext attribute) {
        return serialize(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public StateMachineContext convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] dbData) {
        return deserialize(dbData);
    }


}
```

I have controller which is responsible to switch states

```
public class ProcessEventController {


    final DefaultStateMachineAdapter<ProcessState, ProcessEvent, ContextEntity<ProcessState, ProcessEvent, ? extends Serializable>> processStateMachineAdapter;

    public ProcessEventController(DefaultStateMachineAdapter<ProcessState, ProcessEvent, ContextEntity<ProcessState, ProcessEvent, ? extends Serializable>> processStateMachineAdapter) {
        this.processStateMachineAdapter = processStateMachineAdapter;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/processes/{id}/{event}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @Transactional
    public HttpEntity<Void> receiveEvent(@PathVariable("id") Process process, @PathVariable("event") ProcessEvent event) throws Exception {
        StateMachine<ProcessState, ProcessEvent> stateMachine = processStateMachineAdapter.restore(process);
        if (stateMachine.sendEvent(event)) {
            processStateMachineAdapter.persist(stateMachine, process);
            return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.unprocessableEntity().build();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can't modify existing running machine but as you're already working with persistence I assume you're at least stopping machines.

Look [statemachine-examples-datajpa](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.2.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-examples-datajpa) which is using existing machine apis to store config in a DB. We have `StateMachineModelFactory` which pretty much allows you to store your stuff anywhere if any build-in implementation is not suitable for you. This sample will build new machine instances every time when new events are sent. i.e. you can go to a DB using build-in editor and add new transition(s) without restarting a main java process.

This gives you some flexibility but if you need to change your running code then things will get impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to add some details of my implementation. And ask again.
I have read documentation once more time and understood that it is not really good way to create state machine from factory each time. 
So first thing which I want to rework is DefaultStateMachineAdapter. It is better to retrieve state machine from pool and reset it to particular state. Correct?

Comment: The second thing, which is more important for me than overhead during instantiating state machine is future changes in state and transitions.
Let's assume that I want to manage process with next states and events: step1--event1-->step2--event2-->step3.
My requirement is that each user of my application can run several processes. For instance user1 make request for my controller and run process1 into state2.

Comment: Let's assume that the application run some long running task when state2 was activated. When this task will be finished the application should change state2 to state3.
Let's suppose that at this moment we want to change the process definition. I mean that I should rework step1--event1--step2-->event2-->step3 on step1--event1-->step2-->event2-->newstep-newevent->step3
So after redeploy my application I want to restore my state and go via new definition.
As I mentioned earlier I failed here.

Comment: So my question is: can I manage this behavior with state machine? Or it is better to switch my activities on other solution like spring-integration.
I am not sure, but I fill that I can manage it if I will resolve the issue with overhead during creation. I mean that if I will retrieve the state machine from the pool instead of persisting it, and reset it to particular state can resolve my problem. Correct?